# Looking for a reference nodejs, expressjs & mongodb app to use as template

Tags: mongodb, node.js, express

I want to build out a nodejs app and was looking for a good reference app to use as a template. Ideally the app will have the following features

1. uses nodejs, expressjs & mongodb
2. has a user authentication subsystem

I'd like to download such an app and have it working out of the box, than i can poke into the code and start customizing it for my needs.

updated:
I've looked at http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb (github repo https://github.com/creationix/howtonode.org/tree/master/articles/express-mongodb ) which is very useful but is somewhat dated. There is a preso at http://www.slideshare.net/robb1e/a-nodejs-application
 that talks a bit more on but no code/app/repo

I'm sure there are a lot of code patterns and other learning that folks have had with real-world apps and I'm looking to see if such an app exists so I can build ontop of best practices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an awesome example of an mvc app using express and mongoose:

https://github.com/cliftonc/express-mvc-bootstrap

Answer (score 3):

I don't know(yet?) about full-flexed applications, but I know a couple of modules which are pretty good. They have proper documentation/samples:

**Templating:**

- [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/): You can use this in express. There are a lot of express/jade screencasts available(google). Even some from author TJ.

**authentication:**

- [everyauth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth): He has some good documentation/examples available.

**mongodb:**

- [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/): Also has some pretty good documentation available and also a pretty good screencast on the mongodb site.

Comment: Hes looking for example applications not libraries ;)

Comment: @Raynos is right i am looking for example apps. But thanks for the pointer on everyauth it has a ton of examples that are useful

Comment: @Raynos I know, but that's what I know and could be rather useful. I don't know any applications yet...

Answer (score 1):

[Examples](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples)

There is a large examples folder on the express github page. Start there.

Comment: i've updated my question to try and be more specific as to what i'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

Look at the NodeTuts.com videos. If you want a small CRUD example with authentication look in my repo here:

https://github.com/alessioalex/Nodetuts/tree/master/express_samples

Answer (score 0):

I have a project that might be useful for some. It is currently a work in progress, but I will try to include som helpful tip along the way.

The title is "Testing setting up a RESTful JSON server with Node, Express, Passport authenticaion and mongoDB with node-mongodb-native."

And it lives here: https://github.com/frodefi/node-mongodb-json-server